# Wordpress site deployed on Elastic Beanstalk randomly reset to install page setup-config.php

Tags: wordpress, amazon-aws

I put up a wordpress website on Elastic Beanstalk, and the other day when I went to my website, it redirected me to the wordpress install page (/wp-admin/setup-config.php). What happened to my website? The database is there in my RDS, but since the credentials are set via environmental variables, I can't connect to it. Does anyone have any idea what happened?

I've set up dozens of Wordpress sites before, but this is my first time using beanstalk, and I've never encountered this before.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is related to Beanstalk, but the install page is triggered if WP can't find `wp-config.php`

Comment: Thanks. I think that Beanstalk resets the contents of your ec2 every once in a while. The problem is (I think) that wp-config.php is made when you initiate the beanstalk app, using EV to set the db credentials. Persistent data is supposed to be stored in an S3 bucket or something. Its all very confusing to me, and frustrating that Elastic Beanstalk, a supposedly push button solution, doesn't work that way.

Comment: can you change permissions to lock the file?  Or maybe clone the original and then run a cron job to replace it if it is edited - though this may be fraught with peril if you intentionally make changes

Comment: I haven't edited the config files. How would I access the orignial wp-config.php file if it was generated by EB? Can I ssh into my EB instance?